# In-place timestamp syntax as argument

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, timestamp, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

From [Oracle document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions059.htm) I noticed a particular syntax

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP '2000-03-28 08:00:00', '3:00') 
   FROM DUAL;
```

How can we define *in-place* timestamp by saying `TIMESTAMP '2000-03-28 08:00:00'` like that ? It's like saying `myFunction(NUMERIC 20)`. I cannot find this or similar rule documented anywhere. Are there similar *in-place* declarations ?

Traditionally I would use `TO_TIMESTAMP()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "In-Place Timestamp" ?

Comment: I mean the syntax TIMESTAMP '2000-03-28 08:00:00' is strange to me. Normally you would not write f(NUMERIC 20) or f(VARCHAR2(10)  'abc'). Yet TIMESTAMP is placed to say this is a timestamp type. so I am asking what kind of syntax is that ?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP('2000-03-28 8:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') 
FROM Dual;
```

Comment: That is what I would normally write. My question is about the grammatical syntax FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP ...) to say "this is a timestamp". We would not write f(NUMERIC 20) I suppose.